# Making a KML layer "always on"

Tags: kml, layers, google-earth, overlay

Is there a KML tag or specification by which you can force a given layer (specifically, a screen overlay) to be "always on", in that there is no way for the user viewing the file to make that layer invisible, so long as they are viewing anything in that file? I'm looking in particular for a solution that will work when Google Earth is used to view the KML file.

That is, if my KML file has multiple features and layers, one of which is called "Overlay", say, then if the user loads my KML file and turns on any of the layers in it, then Overlay will automatically turn on. If the user tries to turn Overlay off while something else in the file is still visible then either (a) Overlay cannot be turned off, or (b) everything else in the file is made invisible along with Overlay.

Of course I have no problem with the user removing my KML file from the GE session, or disabling it entirely, but if any of it is shown, then Overlay should be as well.

Comment: I seriously doubt that functionality exists.  Though, have you looked [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/)?  I don't think the user would like their GE hijacked in that way.

Comment: I have looked there, and tried googling. I came across a [Google Groups post from 2006](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kml-support-getting-started/vuOJ-37IVuY/rj7f_RylJjMJ) that said it wasn't possible then, but not much else. I've reworded my question based on your comment re hijacking, because I don't think what I'm really after is all that sinister.

Answer (score 1):

First Create a folder. For example, name the folder "TOGETHER". Uncheck the "Allow this folder to be expanded" box. Move the desired feature "Overlay" into this "TOGETHER" folder, along with all of the other features. Now all of the features will be turned on or off together with a single click.